# How can I set a custom form of my Bill of materials in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, bom

Actually I have made a schematic and I want to adopt the same format as in this file which was based on database [image]
because when I run bom.ulp I get only a such table :[image]. I know that is something generated using 'Database' and 'Output'[image] [image]but I don't know how to manage it.
Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the Attribute tool and updating each device you are using in your schematic.

With that tool you can create fields according to the information you want to generate to the BOM.

You also can create a script and run it when you need to create the fields for each device. Here is an example:

```
ATTRIBUTE MANUFACTURER_NAME variable
ATTRIBUTE MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER variable
ATTRIBUTE DATASHEET_URL variable
ATTRIBUTE VENDOR_ID variable
ATTRIBUTE VENDOR_PART_NUMBER variable
ATTRIBUTE REFERENCE_PRICE variable
```

After doing this you can generate the BOM and have all the columns you want.